# python, pd.merge pierde datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy tratando de aunar 2 *df* en 1 solo.

*df1*

```txt
    Municipios  Poblacion   Edad    Año
0   Total   1089051 65 -100 años y mas  2022
1   Acebeda, La 300 65 -100 años y mas  2022
2   Ajalvir 5410    65 -100 años y mas  2022
3   Alameda del Valle   610 65 -100 años y mas  2022
4   Álamo, El   18910   65 -100 años y mas  2022
```

*df2*

```txt
    Municipios  Plazas titularidad privada  Plazas titularidad pública  plazas
0   Alamo (El)  638.0   0.0 638.0
1   Alcalá de Henares   978.0   653.0   1631.0
2   Alcobendas  887.0   201.0   1088.0
3   Alcorcón    470.0   218.0   688.0
4   Aldea del Fresno    165.0   0.0 165.0
```

```python
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 109 entries, 0 to 108
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column                      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                      --------------  ----- 
 0   Municipios                  109 non-null    object
 1   Plazas titularidad privada  109 non-null    object
 2   Plazas titularidad pública  109 non-null    object
 3   plazas                      109 non-null    object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 3.5+ KB
```

```python
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 180 entries, 0 to 179
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   Municipios  180 non-null    object
 1   Poblacion   180 non-null    object
 2   Edad        180 non-null    object
 3   Año         180 non-null    object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 11.1+ KB
```

Estoy usando el siguiente código:

```python
df_merged = pd.merge(residencias_madrid, pob_Madrid_65_mas, how= "outer")
df_merged.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

y me devuelve esto:

```txt
    Municipios  Plazas titularidad privada  Plazas titularidad pública  plazas  Poblacion   Edad    Año
0   Alamo (El)  638.0   0.0 638.0   0   0   0
1   Alcalá de Henares   978.0   653.0   1631.0  0   0   0
2   Alcobendas  887.0   201.0   1088.0  0   0   0
3   Alcorcón    470.0   218.0   688.0   0   0   0
4   Aldea del Fresno    165.0   0.0 165.0   0   0   0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
284 Villar del Olmo 0   0   0   3080    65 -100 años y mas  2022
285 Villarejo de Salvanés   0   0   0   12890   65 -100 años y mas  2022
286 Villaviciosa de Odón    0   0   0   17823   65 -100 años y mas  2022
287 Villavieja del Lozoya   0   0   0   560 65 -100 años y mas  2022
288 Zarzalejo   0   0   0   3030    65 -100 años y mas  2022
```

En las primeras filas me devuelve las datos del `df1` pero los del `df2` me pierde los datos, a partir de no se qué punto cambia y del `df1` me pierde los datos, pero empieza a traermelos de df2...
¿Alguien que pueda dar un poco de luz?

Comment: Hola, para aclarar, ¿no te refieres al truncado del dataframe al imprimirlo? Me refiero a imprimir hasta la fila 4 y luego pasar a la 284. Si es esto, no estas perdiendo datos, tu datframe tiene 288 filas, es solo que pandas trunca su representación si la longitud excede lo preestablecido para no "saturar" la terminal.  Prueba con `with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None,'display.precision', 3,): print(df_merged)`.